# @propertyWrapper for Optional type: wrappedValue initialization error for automatically assigned nil value

Tags: swift, initialization, option-type

I faced strange error when usign propertyWrapper feature. Sample code below:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Wrapper<Value> {
    private var parameter: Int?

    var wrappedValue: Value

    init(wrappedValue: Value, parameter: Int? = 0) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self.parameter = parameter
    }
}

class WrapperTest {
    @Wrapper var valueImplicitNil: Double?                                  // OK
    @Wrapper var valueExplicitNil: Double? = nil                            // OK
    //@Wrapper(parameter: 1) var valueWithParamImplicitNil: Double?           // NOK (Missing argument for parameter 'wrappedValue' in call)
    @Wrapper(parameter: 1) var valueWithParamExplicitNil: Double? = nil    // OK
}
```

For `valueImplicitNil`, Swift automatically assigns `nil` to it, and then propertyWrapper initializer automatically assigns `nil` to first `init` parameter `wrappedValue` - both behaviours clearly described in Swift documentation.

For some reason it doesn't do the same for `valueWithParamImplicitNil` variable. Any ideas, why is it so?

EDIT: As advised, I reported an issue SR-14411 in bugs.swift.org, and am using workaround proposed below.

Comment: I expect you've just pushed the compiler past what it can handle. It's probably legal, but quite complex, and property wrappers are pretty new. I recommend opening a report at bugs.swift.org.

Answer (score 0):

Here property wrapper is a struct, therefore all its properties must be initialized when an instance is created. In your example, no value is given, so the compiler emits an error.

Your property wrapper struct takes a non-optional wrappedValue - it can’t be initialised without a value. If you don’t provide one you get a compiler error as you can see.

If you want a property wrapper that doesn’t require an initial wrapper value  then you need to make wrappedValue optional.

Comment: But I'm providing a value. Following Swift documentation: (1) If you define an optional variable without providing a default value, the variable is automatically set to nil for you:. (2). When you include property wrapper arguments, you can also specify an initial value using assignment. Swift treats the assignment like a wrappedValue argument and uses the initializer that accepts the arguments you include.      It works properly for first variable of class WrappedTest. But _the_same_ rules doesn't work for 3rd variable. There's no difference between them except 2nd paramater. Strange?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, this looks like a compiler bug. Basically, the compiler should be able to fill in the first parameter for the initializer (`wrappedValue`) in the second case also, since clearly it can handle the default value for nil properties if no arguments are passed to the property declaration.

So, if `@Wrapper var valueImplicitNil: Double?` gets expanded by the compiler to

```swift
private var _valueImplicitNil = Wrapper<Double?>(wrappedValue: nil)
var valueImplicitNil: Double? {
    get { return _valueImplicitNil.wrappedValue }
    set { _valueImplicitNil.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

, so it should be the case for `@Wrapper(parameter: 1) var valueWithParamImplicitNil: Double?`, which should expand to:

```swift
private var _valueImplicitNil = Wrapper<Double?>(wrappedValue: nil, parameter: 1)
var valueImplicitNil: Double? {
    get { return _valueImplicitNil.wrappedValue }
    set { _valueImplicitNil.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

A workaround until this gets fixed in the compiler is to add another initializer that has only the second argument:

```swift
init<V>(parameter: Int? = 0) where Value == V? {
    self.init(wrappedValue: nil, parameter: parameter)
}
```

At least this is the approach `AppStorage` took, so it seems that the Apple engineers ran into the same problem, but found a way to work around this limitation.

Comment: I was close with similiar workaround, but had no idea how to check wheter Value is optional. And here it is. Very clever (at least for me). Thx a lot! BTW. I reported an issue SR-14411 as advised by Rob Napier. Related problem (deffered initialization of property wrapper with parameter) is referenced in SR-14411 discussion. Interesting. Thx again.